# How can I send CSV from React app to Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, sockets

In my React app I have an input with type="file". I want to upload my CSV file in this input and send it to my Node.js server, but it doesnt work. Also, there is a problem that my server gives only 6 uotputs and then nothing. I am new in js and React, so answer in details please;)

My App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {
  const [csvFile, SetCsvFile] = useState();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div>
          Select file
          <input type="file" name="file" onChange={e => {
            SetCsvFile(e.target.files)
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', "FILENAME");
            formData.append('file', csvFile);
            const url = 'http://localhost:8080/EXPRESSENDPOINT';
            axios({
              method: 'POST',
              url: url,
              headers: {
                ContentType: 'multipart/form-data'
              },
              body: formData
            })
              .then(res => console.log(res))
              .catch(err => console.log(err));
          }} />
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

My server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const CsvUpload = require("express-fileupload");

app.use(CsvUpload());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/EXPRESSENDPOINT',
    (req, res, next) => { console.log(req.body)});

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Application listening on port 8080!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two things wrong in your server:

- your endpoint is not returning a response, which leaves the request hanging
- you are checking for the file in the wrong place. [see usage instructions of that package](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload#usage)

Try this in your route instead:

```
app.use('/upload', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.files)
    res.sendStatus(200)
});
```

Note: It would be good if you posted the logs from Node.